# Regex - Strip off (1) from filename

Tags: c#, regex

I have some files that have the same name but have "(1)" "(2)" "(3)" append to them.  Unfortunately I'm horrible with regex. Can someone help me with the regex string to strip off the trailing (2) from the entire filename.

For example:

```
MyFile(1).jpg >> MyFile.jpg
AnotherFile(3).docx >> AnotherFile.docx
Last.Example.Boo(999).xlsx >> Last.Example.Boo.xlsx
```

Thanks SO!

Comment: probably don't even need a regex. split the filename into basename + extension, then a simple substring operation based on the position of the LAST `(` would do the trick...

Comment: I was going to do that, but I was ended up with files like 'myfilename(2)(3).gif" if (2) already existed. I want to strip it off so I can sequentially test (1) then (2) then (3)... until I find a filename not in use.

Comment: that just means you didn't use the "stripped" version to build the new filename.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it can be done like this:

```
string name = "Last.Example.Boo(999).xlsx";
string newName = Regex.Replace(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name), @"\(\d+\)$", "") 
    + Path.GetExtension(name);
```

This will remove last occurence of `(any_number)` in file name.

Answer (score 1):

Through regex, it would be done like this,

```
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"\(\d+\)(?=\.[^.]+$)", "");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jX1jL8/1)